# Adding new tab to JTabbedPane then refresh that JTabbedPane

Tags: java, refresh, jtabbedpane

I've got a problem refreshing JTabbedPane. 
After pushing button addGroup from class jPanelAddTabAddShortcut application creates a new file ( works fine).

The number of tabbs depends on number of those files so if i add 1 more file, application needs to recalculate that number (static variable "intFileCount" which is set in readFiles()) and then add last tab to JTabbedPane.

In short readFiles() sets "intFileCount"(number of tabbs/files), readTabNames() sets strTabName[] (tabbs names) and then tabbedPanne() returns JTabbedPane with all tabbs added.

I tried to add those 3 methods to button action listener and revalidate+repaint JTabbedPane but it doesnt work. I Tried to use removeALL() before that but that didnt work too.

Its possible i made some misteake while setting "intFileCount" variable when adding file (jPanelAddTabAddShortcut class->addGroup action listener part and saveTabNames() method). That might be my misteak but after thinkig a long time i thought more experienced people should look at this.

When i rerun application new tab is added correctly.

Here is code (i tried to comment everything as best as i could):

```
public class SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2 {
// main JFrame Class + beforeShowingJFrame()
class mainJFrame extends JFrame 
    {
    public mainJFrame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
        //things to do before JFrame shows up
        beforeShowingJFrame();

        //Add JTabbedPane
        jTabbedPane = tabbedPane();
        add(jTabbedPane);

        //JFrame Properties
        setTitle("Skróty Aplikacji");
        setSize(1024, 768);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
// JPanel used only as background
class JBackgroundPanel extends JPanel 
    {
    private BufferedImage img;
    JBackgroundPanel()
        {
        try
            {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("2.jpg"));
            } 
        catch (IOException e) 
            {
            }
        }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
        }
    }
// Jpanel containing pair of (button+jtextarea) -> added to containterPanel
class addShortcut extends JPanel
    {
    private addShortcut(Icon p,String s,final String strin) 
        {
        GridBagLayout gbLayout2 = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        super.setLayout(gbLayout2);

        p=resizeIcon(p);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton(p); 
        btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (50,50));
        JTextArea ShortcutDescription = new JTextArea();
        ShortcutDescription.setLineWrap(true);
        ShortcutDescription.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ShortcutDescription.setText(s);

        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                try 
                    {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+ strin);
                    } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                    Logger.getLogger(SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        ShortcutDescription.setOpaque(false);
        this.setOpaque(false);
        ShortcutDescription.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,10));
        ShortcutDescription.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        //nazwaIkonki.getViewport().setOpaque(false); 
        ShortcutDescription.setEditable(false);
        d.gridy=0;
        this.add(btn1,d);
        d.gridy=1;
        this.add(ShortcutDescription,d);
        } 
    }
// JPanel used to add new Tabbs/Files
class jPanelAddTabAddShortcut extends JPanel
    {
    //Dodanie komponentow
    JTextField newTabName= new JTextField("Nazwa Nowej Grupy");;   
    JTextField newShortcutDescription = new JTextField("Nazwa Nowego Skrótu");
    JButton addGroup = new JButton("Dodaj Grupę"); 
    JButton addShortcut = new JButton("Dodaj Skrót"); 

        jPanelAddTabAddShortcut() 
        {
        //Ustawianie Wymiarow
        newTabName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,20));
        addGroup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (130,20));
        newShortcutDescription.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,20));
        addShortcut.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,20));
        //Ustawienie czcionki
        newTabName.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,10));
        newShortcutDescription.setFont(new Font("verdana",Font.BOLD,10));
        //Ustawienie widocznosci
        this.setOpaque(false);

        //JButton dodajacy nowa grupe 
        //Refresh zakladek
        addGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                // dodana nazwa grupy
                strTabName[intFileCount] = newTabName.getText();
                //Tworzenie pliku dla danej grupy
                File f=new File(Integer.toString(intFileCount)+".txt");
                try 
                    {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                    Logger.getLogger(SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                //Zapis grupy do pliku
                try 
                    {
                    saveTabNames();
                    } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                    Logger.getLogger(SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                //zmienna grup zwiekszona o +1
                intFileCount++;
                }
            });

        this.add(newTabName);
        this.add(addGroup);
        this.add(addShortcut);
        this.add(newShortcutDescription);
        } 
    }
    SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
        mainJFrame=new mainJFrame();
        mainJFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
        {
        SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2 skrotyAplikacjiTabbed2 = new SkrotyAplikacjiTabbed2();
        }
    // resize icon to 40,40
    Icon resizeIcon(Icon d)
        {
        Image img = iconToImage(d);
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(40,40,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        d= new ImageIcon(newimg);
        return d;
        }
    // icon -> image
    Image iconToImage(Icon icon)
        {
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon)
            {
            return ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage();
            }
        else
            {
            int w = icon.getIconWidth();
            int h = icon.getIconHeight();
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w,h);
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            icon.paintIcon(null, g, h, h);
            g.dispose();
            return image;
            }
        } 
    // returns JTabbedPane with all Tabbs added
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane()
        {
        JTabbedPane tempJTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<intFileCount;j++) 
            {
            tempJTabbedPane.addTab(strTabName[j],jBackgroundPanel[j]);
            }
        return tempJTabbedPane;
        }
    // things to do before JFrame shows up
    void beforeShowingJFrame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
        readFiles();
        readTabNames();
        settingPanels();
        addingTabComponents();
        }
    // read Files (sets static intFileCount and intTabComponentCount)
    // gets necessary info about shortcut(link,description,icon etc)
    void readFiles() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
        for(intFileCount=0;intFileCount<1000;intFileCount++)
            {
            String a;
            a = Integer.toString(intFileCount);
            File f = new File(a+".txt");
            if(f.exists())
                {
                intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]=0;
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                    {
                    strLinksList[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]=scanner.nextLine();
                    strFileList[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]= new File(strLinksList[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]);
                    iconFileIcon[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]= fsv.getSystemIcon(strFileList[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]);
                    strShortcutDescription[intFileCount][intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]]=scanner.nextLine();
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    intTabComponentCount[intFileCount]++;     
                    }
                }
            else break;
            }
        }
    // read each tab name from a file
    void readTabNames() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileGroupFile);
        for (int j=0; j<intFileCount;j++)
            {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                strTabName[j]=scanner.nextLine();   
                }    
            }
        }
    // adds jScrollPane[j] to jBackgroundPane[j]
    // then adds containerPanel[j] to jScrollPane[j]
    // sets panels properties
    void settingPanels()
        {
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<intFileCount;j++)
            {
            //inicjalizacja paneli
            jBackgroundPanel[j] = new JBackgroundPanel();
            containterPanel[j] = new JPanel();

            //wlasciwosci paneli
            containterPanel[j].setVisible(true);
            containterPanel[j].setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            containterPanel[j].setOpaque(false);
            jBackgroundPanel[j].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jScrollPane[j] = new JScrollPane(containterPanel[j]);
            jScrollPane[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
            jScrollPane[j].setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            jScrollPane[j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(530,386));
            jScrollPane[j].setOpaque(false);
            jScrollPane[j].getViewport().setOpaque(false);
            jBackgroundPanel[j].add(jScrollPane[j],BorderLayout.WEST);           
            jBackgroundPanel[j].add(new jPanelAddTabAddShortcut(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
            }
        }    
    // saves edited Tab names to file
    public void saveTabNames() throws IOException
        {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileGroupFile);
        for (int j=0; j<intFileCount+1;j++)
            {
            printWriter.println(strTabName[j]);
            printWriter.flush();
            }
        }
    // add pair of (jbutton+jtextarea) to chosen containterPanel[]
    // using method addShortcut
    void addingTabComponents()
    {
    int j,k;
    for (j=0;j<intFileCount;j++)    
        {
        v=0;
        q=0;
        for (k=0;k<intTabComponentCount[j];k++)
            {
            c.gridx=v;
            c.gridy=q;
            c.insets= new Insets(5,5,5,5);
            containterPanel[j].add(new addShortcut(iconFileIcon[j][k],strShortcutDescription[j][k],strLinksList[j][k]),c);
            if(v<4)
                {
                v++;
                }
            if (v==4)
                {
                v=0;
                q++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //readFiles() Variables
    static int intFileCount=0; // counts tabbs
    static int[] intTabComponentCount= new int[1000]; // counts components added to related tab

    //GridBagLayout Variables
    int v=0,q=0; // gridx and gridy
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Tab Variables
    String[] strTabName = new String [1000];   // tab names 
    final File fileGroupFile = new File("grupy.txt"); // file containig tab names
    File fileNewShortcutFile;  // variable storing temporary file which will be set as a new tab

    //Shortcut Componnents Variables
    String[][] strShortcutDescription = new String [1000][1000]; // description below shortcut
    Icon[][] iconFileIcon = new Icon[1000][1000]; // shortcut icon
    String[][] strLinksList = new String[1000][1000]; // shortcut link
    File[][] strFileList = new File[1000][1000]; // File linked to related shortcut

    //Other Variables
    JBackgroundPanel[] jBackgroundPanel = new JBackgroundPanel[1000]; // background JPanel
    JScrollPane[] jScrollPane = new JScrollPane[1000]; // added to background Jpanel
    JPanel[] containterPanel = new JPanel[1000]; // added to JScrollPane; contains shortcuts + their descriptions
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView(); // used to get file icon
    JTabbedPane jTabbedPane;  // JTabbedPane
    mainJFrame mainJFrame;  // main JFrame
}
```

Comment: You should consider writing your code in English, especially variables, functions, methods, classes and such. It'll be easier to read for others, you won't get weird naming conflicts if you use foreign characters and so forth. Generally, just use your own language for text output, and maybe comments.

Comment: Still using "static" everywhere. Still using setPreferredSize(). You have been given suggestions not to do this in your other postings. For a new suggestion, don't use Arrays with some random hard coded value. Use ArrayLists. You can't write/debug a progrom if it is not properly designed. I'm not even going to look until the code is cleaned up.

Comment: Timss:next time ill do as you say.truth is i started this project before i thought id need other persons help.
@camickr i understand you dislike the fact that i didnt do many changes according to advices from before.its not becouse i didnt want to.I just started to learn java recently and even if im trying  I cant use every advice with my level of knowledge. For You its easy. For me its not. Right now I focus on making this application work. Then im gonna focus on other things.Ofc im not expecting you to correct my code so im just gonna say "thanks for advice". Ill try to make best use of it.

Comment: `I just started to learn java recently` - so learn how to do it properly. There is a reason for doing code the proper way. It is easier to maintain, easier to debug and easier to change. It is also easier to learn how to do things right the first time then it is to relearn something. People have not answer this question because we don't understand why you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: Robert, it can be frustrating to give advice, only to see it ignored. Many of us stop giving advice when that happens, since we fear it will only be ignored again.

Comment: @camickr i spend whole night to get rid of those statics and i followed timisses advice too and rewrote my code in English. i hope its better now. Should be easier to read. im still using setPreferredSize() tho. will think about changing it later. Before using ArrayLists i need to learn how to use them so pls be patient with me. For now is is possible for you to help me with main problem (refreshing JTabbedPane)? im seriously trying my best here.